# two rotations to rebalance avl tree after delete node

Tags: data-structures, avl-tree

I learn about AVL trees and rotations. Is there a situation that after deleting a node from the tree we will need TWO rotations to re-balance the tree?
I'm not talking about RL/LR/RR/LL rotations, I mean to use them TWICE.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/avl-tree-set-2-deletion/, and view the video linked in that article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. You need to travel up the tree from the deleted node until you find the first unbalanced node but after that you need only one rotation to fix it.